# Check whether post a feed to Facebook succesfully or not

Tags: android, facebook

I've been searching for a while how to do that, 
And I modify my Display.java like:

```
public class Display extends ListActivity {
.
.
.

public class WallPostRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {

    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        Display.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successfully shared on Facebook!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to use `Toast` to show a message when it is successfully posted. I failed doing that. 
But I can see the post on my facebook home page.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't checking for the response do the trick. If the response code is 200 then I reckon you can be certain that the post has been successful.

Comment: how about trying getApplicationContext() instead of getBaseContext() ?

Comment: Have you tried displaying a log cat message instead of a toast? Let me know if it works.